# CSS "break-out" of Bootstrap rows/columns to make a background the whole browser-width

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

[image]I have a complex Bootstrap-4 grid-layout. Now, suddenly inside a column, I need to make the background (not the content!) reach from left of the browser-window to the right of the browser-window, the whole width. Is there any way this can be done?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h2 class="font-weight-light">Hello!</h2>
            <p>
                This background should stay white.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mybackground">
        <div class="col">          
            The red background should fill ALL of the browser-width from left to right, but keep the area above and below with white background.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/enu2vxdw/

If you look at the fiddle, the background of < div class="mybackground" >  should reach from left to right (no white paddings left and right), but the content of it should stay as it is.

Any idea how to do this with the least amount of changes (because unfortunately there are a lot places in the code where this needs to be done, so a simple css-class would be awesome).

Comment: Werner what do you mean by `should reach from left to right `

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added a picture to make it clearer.

Comment: You can not apply a background outside of the dimensions of an element. If you don’t want to break the whole grid here to make the element itself full-width (and then limit the width of the actual content inside it again), then you might need to use an actual image (or at least a helper element, that a background image can then be applied to), and combine it with this technique: https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/

Comment: Thank you, the link is very helpfull to see what's possible (and what's not).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding rows inside a container, you should now have sections with containers.

An example:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <h2 class="font-weight-light">Hello!</h2>
        <p>This background should stay white.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <h2 class="font-weight-light">Hello!</h2>
        <p>This background should stay white.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row bg-danger text-white">
      <!--div class="col"-->
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <p class="mt-3">The red background should fill ALL of the browser-width from left to right, but keep the area above and below with white background.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
      <!--/div-->
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

The `container-fluid` can stretch full width. To align the content you'll have to introduce a `container` again.
You'll end up with quite a lot of nesting which doesn't look too pretty but I don't know another Bootstrap way around this.

This result will be fully responsive regarding the spacing.